# jQuery resizable not working on ajaxically loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, resizable

I have following div on my page:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="resizable">some content</div>
</div>
```

I have following function to make it resizable:

```
$(function(){
   $('div#resizable').resizable();
});
```

Till here everything works fine and I have resize handle in bottom right corner of the div, but on click of function the inner div is loaded again from the server:

```
$('#button').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"myurl",
       type:"post",
       success:function(data)
      {
         $("#container").html(data);
         $("div#resizable").resizable();
      }
     });
});
```

Even though I'm calling resizable function in ajax callback but it doesn't seem to work. I can't see resize handle in bottom right corner of ajaxically loaded div. The id is right everything is same. What might be the problem?

Comment: The solution for this question appears to be trivial and thus is not likely to help many other developers. With that in mind I think this question can be closed under the "Typo" reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my mistake. I had two ajax calls in callback method of one call I added `.resizable` method but in the other I didn't.

Comment: I have same problem with resize & in my case I added resizable() in my both the ajax call but still it not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ID in an HTML element must be unique in an HTML page. Instead you could use the classname 'resizable' for every element you wat to be resizable.

When you change to the class resizable the jquery command has to be changed to:

$("div.resizable").resizable();

The hash (#) is changed into a dot (.)

Comment: i have done it with class name as well but that doesn't seem to be the problem